# improve remote control app command latency

Tags: flutter, ros, latency, robotics, remote-control

Is there a way to increase joystick command speed from my Flutter app to my robot? Right now I’m using wifi (which has other data streaming back to the tablet) and there is a lag between commands and robot motion. This is not an issue when I use a wireless 2.4GHz Logitech controller.

https://pub.dev/packages/control_pad

Comment: Normally, the latency of wifi is very low, because of the high throughput. You could write your own sockets for the commands which speeds the whole process or you can use bluetooth aswell.